# Language detection redirect (homepage)

Tags: redirect, multilingual

I have a website in multiple languages with a language detection system.
If a user types the URL http://the-domain.com, and assuming that the system detects the Portuguese language, which is the best solution?

1. Show the contents in Portuguese at the same URL http://the-domain.com
2. Redirect to http://the-domain.com/pt and display the content in Portuguese

NOTE: this question is about homepage link

Answer (score 0):

The problem with different languages on the same URL is, that different people will get different results. Which could be confusing and it might not help with SEO.
So I would recommend the redirect.

Update:
This answers the "multiple languages on the same url" question:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47390/seo-implications-of-having-multiple-languages-available-at-same-url

Comment: You said "The problem with different languages on the same URL...it might not help with SEO" but I must be sure about that.

Comment: Your answer is right for all pages of a website but my question is about homepage and I think it's a bit different.

Comment: It's still the same issue. You have a URL that has different languages. But then again, it's one URL of many, so I don't think it matters too much.

Comment: I found one article from Google and seems that we have various configurations and both solution 1 and solution 2 are ok to use. https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your.html